# @protocol implementation in @interface in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

I need to develop an application which has a interface which implements methods of 3 protocols.
Assume protocol A extends protocol B and protocol C, and interface implements protocol A.
This is how my code looks,

```
// This is in MyClass.h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "protocol_A"
@interface MyClass : NSObject <protocol_A>
{
}
@end

//This is MyClass.m file
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation myClass

-(void)methodinA
{
NSLog(@"I'm in protocol_A");
}
}
-(void)methodinB
{
NSLog(@"I'm in protocol_B");
}

-(void)methodinC
{
NSLog(@"I'm in protocol_C");
}

@end

//This is protocol_A.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "protocol_B.h"
#import "protocol_C.h"

@protocol protocol_A <protocol_B, protocol_C>

-(void)methodinA;
@end

//This is in protocol_B.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol protocol_B
   -(void)methodinB;
@end

//This is in protocol_C.h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol protocol_C
   -(void)methodinC;
@end
```

i'm getting an exception , and my app is getting crashed...

```
***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyClass 0X323nm31>setvalue:forundefinedKey:]:this class is not key value coding-compilant for the key window'.
```

Plz Tel me how to solve this problem??

Comment: The crash is entirely unrelated to the protocols. Ask a different question.  I'd bet that you have a 'window' binding in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So where you're getting this from (and the reason you're getting it 3 times) is you've got a mistake in your protocol definitions. You have:

```
//This is in protocol_C.h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol protocol_C
{
}
-(void)methodinC;
@end
```

You can't declare class members in a protocol: only methods. Because of this, you don't need (and, as you've discovered) *can't have* the curly braces in the protocol definition. As such, you need this for your protocol definitions:

```
//This is in protocol_C.h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol protocol_C

-(void)methodinC;

@end
```

Removing those should solve your issue.

When making new files, I always go through Xcode's new-class-files process, as it frequently gives you lots of convenient stuff. Here is the contents of a new protocol_D declaration fresh from Xcode:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@protocol protocol_D


@end
```

Hope this helps!

TL;DR: Protocol definitions can't have curly-braces anywhere in them.

Comment: Hey.. super!!! thanks ... :) i'm getting this Exception regarding, ***Terminating app due to uncaught excception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyClass 0X231nm21> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'

Comment: You'll need to post your actual code to try to solve this. Could you copy-and-paste the exact error message you see, too?

Comment: above what i've written is the actual codem and also i've copy - n - pasted the same error

Answer (score 0):

Protocols generally go in a .h file;  always go in a .h file if you plan on using them anywhere.

Just like everything else, you need to `#import` the .h file that contains the definition of the protocol before you use it.

So, in MyClass.h (it really should be capitalized -- Classes are always capitalized in Objective-C), #import the various protocol .h files.

Comment: hi,... i've edited my code above, i've done #import <protocol_A> in MyClass.h file., since tat is the only protocol i'm implementing in MyClass, because inturn it extends other protocol_B and protocol_C, i'll be defining all methos in MyClass. 
i'm not ablt to find out what the mistake,. plz help..

Comment: Should i import protocol_B and protocol_C also in MyClass.h??

Comment: @suse: Your `protocol_A` header should import `protocol_B` and `protocol_C` headers if it extends those protocols.

Comment: hey thanks.. i knw it was a silly mistake.. :P... but stil i'm getting ***ERROR:Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token ***thrice , wats it related to... ??

Comment: @bbum: Can methods in protocol have return type and parameter passing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `protocol_A.h` file declares conformance to `protocol_B` and `protocol_C`, yet you haven't imported the headers for `protocol_B` and `protocol_C`. This means that you are declaring conformance to protocols that as far as the compiler is concerned, don't exist in `protocol_A.h`. You need to import the headers:

In **protocol_A.h**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "protocol_B.h"  //note these new imports
#import "protocol_C.h"

@protocol protocol_A <protocol_B, protocol_C>
-(void)methodinA;
@end
```

Comment: hey thanks...but stil i'm getting ***ERROR:Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token ***thrice , wats it related to... ??

Comment: You have a typo in `MyClass.m`,  `@impelemntation` should be `@implementation`.

Comment: hey.. no.. in my code its proper.. its only a typo error in code in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Also see Apple's [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html), which discusses delegates, protocols, and selectors. Though its listed under Mac OS X, most (if not all) appears to apply to iOS also.