# Hide Button in another-view from Modal View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my iPhone app, I have two UIViewcontroler class firstView and secondView.

From the firstView, I am presenting secondView using `presentModalViewController:animated:` method.

Problem is that when I am dismissing secondView, I want to hide button in firstView.

Although It does execute the code in firstView `[button setHidden:YES];`, but still it does not hide the button.

What could be wrong?

Comment: How about implementing protocol?

Comment: are you hiding button from secondview in dismissModelView method ?

Comment: I tried with protocol but it didn't work.

Comment: @mithilesh ya using object of firstview i  tried to hide button even i tried it by calling viewwillappear of firstview and in there i wrote [button setHidden:YES];

Comment: protocols are used in this kind of situation only. See you must be doing something wrong. Post code.

Comment: @Prerak: I have edited my answer and added protocol implementation. Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have declared property and synthesized the IBOutlet `button`.

Make an object of FirstViewController in SecondViewController.h and property and synthesize it.

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController {
.
.
FirstViewController *firstView;
.
.
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) FirstViewController *firstView;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
@implementation SecondViewController 
.
.
@synthesize firstView;
.
.
@end
```

Now when you present a modal view from firstView

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)presentModalView {
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondView.firstView = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

Now in SecondViewController where you dismiss SecondViewController just add this code.

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)dismissModalView {
    [self.firstView.button setHidden:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Refer to this link:

[@protocol implementation in @interface in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242101/protocol-implementation-in-interface-in-objective-c)

**EDIT-2: With Protocol implementation**

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
    - (void)hideButton;
@end

@interface SecondViewController {
.
.
id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
.
.
}
@property (retain) id delegate;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
@implementation SecondViewController 
.
.
@synthesize delegate;
.
.
@end
```

Now when you present a modal view from firstView

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>
{
.
.
.
.
}
.
.
@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)presentModalView {
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondView.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - SecondViewController Delegate

- (void)hideButton
  {
      [self.button setHidden:YES]; //Here button is UIButton you want to hide when second view is dismissed.
  }
```

Now in SecondViewController where you dismiss SecondViewController just add this code.

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)dismissModalView {
    [delegate hideButton];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Let me know if you need more help on this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for answer but i am trying to implement with protocol can u help me for that

Comment: @Prerak: Also my answer here is very much like protocol implementation apart from the fact that there is no `@protocol` declaration for the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

I would hide the button on the viewDidDissapear method, so when users calls the model the button hides. But this will only work if you cannot show other viewControllers from your firstViewController.

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I created two controller, FirstViewController and SecondViewController.
And one button in each controller.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{
   BOOL firstTime;// to hide button 
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   if (firstTime) {
     [myButton setHidden:TRUE];
   }
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
   firstTime   =   TRUE;
   SecondViewController *secondController  =   [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
   [self presentModalViewController:secondController animated:TRUE];
   [secondController release];
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *secondButton;
- (IBAction)secondButtonClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)secondButtonClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)secondButtonClicked:(id)sender {
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

This worked for me. Please try it out.

Comment: This is a work around and not a standard way to work out the logic. Standard way is either using object as I did or protocol implementation. It seems you are a fresher in iPhone.

Comment: why do u want to use a protocol for such an easy stuff? You are calling the SecondViewController from FirstViewController, right? To get the access of the button in SecondViewController, you can get it form the parentcontroller of SecondViewController which is FirstViewController.